# ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zone.js/dist/zone'

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular 8, that uses karma/jasmine to run some unit tests. I can run tests by executing the following command `ng test` but I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'zone.js/dist/zone' in
>   'C:\PrjNET\Elevation3\FW\4.00\Project\Framework\Development\Client\ElevationJS\shell\src'
>   resolve 'zone.js/dist/zone' in
>   'C:\PrjNET\Elevation3\FW\4.00\Project\Framework\Development\Client\ElevationJS\shell\src'

Any one know how to solve it?

Comment: Try `npm i zone.js`

Comment: @GopeshSharma I have installed and still does not work

Comment: In your test file are you importing `zone.js/dist/zone`?. If yes try changing it to `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';` Though zone-testing only exists from `zone.js 0.8.19`

Comment: @GopeshSharma Yes I know, but I'm importing well (`import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'`). Also, I'm using the version `0.8.29`

Comment: I had the same issue today and I checked the above answers. Although a simple npm install did the trick. My latest pull had a new package that I hadn't added to my local repository and the solution was a simple npm install.

Comment: This is a different problem but I stumbled onto this question. Maybe someone will profit from it: Update zone.js to something higher than 0.11 and change the zone import in the polyfill.ts to import 'zone.js';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that my test configurations on `tsconfig.spec.json` were wrong. So I change from this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.es5.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.es5.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And the error disapeared!

Comment: This answer doesn't help much without knowing your effective combined configuraiton.

Comment: Getting the following error 'Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/anshuman/Documents/repos/jovian-genai-hackathon/UI/zone.js' in '/home/anshuman/Documents/repos/jovian-genai-hackathon/UI''

Answer (score 24):

I fixed it in my project with this command:

```
npm install zone.js@0.11.3 --save
```

I was getting this error using `zone.js@0.8.29`.

Answer (score 8):

`zone-testing` only exists from `0.8.19`. Try to install the latest version. using:

```
npm i zone.js
```

above command worked in my case.

Comment: This also helps when running the app and you get this error.

Comment: solved my problem, ty

Answer (score 6):

**Change**

```
   zone.js/dist/zone
```

**to**

```
   zone.js
```

As for me, **updating** the version did **NOT** work.

I checked the project created with "ng new project", and in the "polyfills.ts" file, it was **"zone.js"** instead of **"zone.js/dist/zone"**.

So I changed it to **"zone.js"**, and it started to work.

**Incorrect:**
[image]

**Correct:**
[image]

Comment: this should be the correct answer !

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is an issue with imports.So I looked for reflect folder inside node_modules/core-js and I copy pasted same path in polyfills.js.
It worked.

from

```
import "core-js/es/reflect";
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
```

to

```
import "core-js/es/reflect";
```

Comment: This can't work if you are doing a CI/CD setup though, right?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar I am not sure.I don't have devops skills.But my code worked in production.